# What happened to direct access "electronic day trading" after 1998-2002?

Tags: equities, market-microstructure, nasdaq, history

I was looking through book catalogues and databases when I noticed something: most books about direct access "electronic day trading" for retail traders were published between 1998-2002, with little afterwards. Examples of the more popular titles are:

- The Electronic Day Trader by Marc Friedfertig, George West — published in 1998.
- How to Get Started in Electronic Day Trading by David Nassar — published in 2001.
- Financial Freedom Through Electronic Day Trading by Van Tharp, Brian June — published in 2001.

If not mistaken, this "electronic day trading" involves direct market access to NASDAQ. I am surprised that there is little of this material after 2002.

What is the reason? Was that style of trading just a fad, or were there structural changes to the market that after 2002 that made the trading method obsolete? What were the structural changes? Did the rise of quantitative finance have a role?

Answer (score 2):

*"What is the reason? Was that style of trading just a fad"*

Doesn't seem surprising that day trading was more popular during a bull than a bear market. I'd guess you'd see the same effect cross-country (e.g. China 2014/2015). Also worth noting that volumes in NDX had peaked in 1Q01 and declined consistently until ~2004.

Comment: Re: "surprised that there is little of this material after 2002". Yes, the stock market downturn of 2002 was quite painful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_market_downturn_of_2002 Trading stocks was no longer "fun".